# why we put those define() in typo3 custom script

Tags: typo3

```
<?php
define('TYPO3_MODE','FE');

require('typo3conf/localconf.php');
require('t3lib/class.t3lib_db.php');
require('t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php');

define('TYPO3_db_host', $typo_db_host);
define('TYPO3_db_username', $typo_db_username);
define('TYPO3_db_password', $typo_db_password);
define('TYPO3_db', $typo_db);

define('PATH_thisScript',str_replace('//','/', str_replace('\\','/', (php_sapi_name()=='cgi'||php_sapi_name()=='isapi' ||php_sapi_name()=='cgi-fcgi')&&($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED']?$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED']:$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'])? ($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED']?$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED']:$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']):($_SERVER['ORIG_SCRIPT_FILENAME']?$_SERVER['ORIG_SCRIPT_FILENAME']:$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))));
define('PATH_site', dirname(PATH_thisScript).'/');

$DB = new t3lib_DB();
$DB->connectDB();
...
```

Question:

In a typo3 custom script, I saw above `define()`, but actually in the whole script, did not use those constants such as `TYPO3_MOD`, `TYPO3_db_host`... why put those `define()` in the script? Or it is the requirement of typo3 system, if so , usually what `define()` should we put into the script?

Comment: You should not bypass the normal bootstrap if TYPO3 unless you really, really know what you are doing. Use an eId script instead. This will take care of a proper bootstrap and you do not need to define those constants then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `t3lib_DB` uses the constants to get the connection to the database used for typo3.

```php
/**
 * Connects to database for TYPO3 sites:
 *
 * @param string $host
 * @param string $user
 * @param string $password
 * @param string $db
 * @return  void
 */
function connectDB($host = TYPO3_db_host, $user = TYPO3_db_username, $password = TYPO3_db_password, $db = TYPO3_db) {
        // If no db is given we throw immediately. This is a sign for a fresh (not configured)
        // TYPO3 installation and is used in FE to redirect to 1-2-3 install tool
        ...
```

But this is not a requirement to get a connection to the database. You can also pass the values directly in `$DB->connectDB();`